# Wrong output with subsets sum algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset-sum

I am using the function given below to recursively check if a subset exists (in a vector) which sums to a given number. Currently, no matter what my target is, the output is true. I have not been able to pinpoint the issue so far.

```
bool check(vector<int> vec, int n, int sum)
{
   if (sum == 0)
   {
     cout << "true" << endl;
     return true;
   }
   if (n == 0 && sum != 0)
   {
     cout << "false" << endl;
     return false;
   }
   if (vec[n-1] > sum)
    return check(vec, n-1, sum); 

   return check(vec, n-1, sum || check(vec, n-1, sum-vec[n-1]));      
}
```

If I add the following snippet to my main and remove the cout lines from my check function, it works perfectly however I want to only call the function in my main and not add any extra lines.

```
 if (check(vec, n, sum) == true)
     cout << "true" << endl;
  else
     cout << "false" << endl;
```

**EDIT**: So I made the following changes to somehow get to the point where the function outputs either true or false when called in main. For example, `check(vec,n,sum,write);`for `vec={1,2,3}` and `sum=4` should just output `true`. Currently I have added an extra parameter to somehow specify when to print the output but no success so far. Any help is appreciated!

```
   bool check(vector<int> vec, int n, int sum, bool write)
    {
       if (sum == 0)
       {
         cout << "true" << endl;
         write=true;
         return true;
       }
       if (n == 0 && sum != 0)
       {
         cout << "false" << endl;
         write=true;
         return false;
       }
       if (vec[n-1] > sum)
        return check(vec, n-1, sum, write=false); 

       return check(vec, n-1, sum, write=false) || check(vec, n-1, sum-vec[n-1], write=false);     

      if (write) {
      cout << check(vec,n,sum,write) << endl;
      }

      }
```

Comment: Optimization tip: every time you call this function (including every recursive call), you are making a copy of the entire vector. Change the first argument from `vector<int>` to `vector<int> const &`.

Comment: Was this line supposed to be as it is? `return check(vec, n-1, sum || check(vec, n-1, sum-vec[n-1]));`

Comment: @Sinstein no, that is a mistake, I have changed it but that doesnt change the initial behavior of the program.

Comment: @sparta93 By your function definition, the 2nd parameter should be the `sum` needed and the 3rd parameter should be the number of elements of vector in consideration, but your recursive call does not seem to comply with that order.

Comment: @sparta93 I think you should change `bool check(vector<int> vec, int sum, int n)` to `bool check(vector<int> vec, int n, int sum)`

Comment: @Sinstein Thanks for that, that actually fixes things. Can't believe I didn't notice it.. but now either true or false is being printed multiple times instead of once.

Comment: That might be because you are printing true/false in the function, and then returning the value and printing it again. Moreover, you could directly print the value of `check (vec, n, sum)` instead of comparing if it is true or false.

Comment: How would I directly print the value of check from within the function without adding any lines to my main? I just want to call my function in main and it should output only either true or false.I have been unsuccessful so far with my attempts.

Comment: @sparta93 just remove the lines starting with `cout` in the function `check()`.

Comment: @Wimmel I get no output if I do that, I'm not sure why. I tried it before.

Comment: @sparta93 I think he means `cout << check(vec, n, sum) << endl;`.

Comment: @cdhowie I see. I don't want to cout in my main though, just calling the function with respective parameters should return either true or false. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @sparta93 in that case rename your function to `check_r`, including the recursive calls. Create a new function `check` which just calls `check_r` and outputs the result.

Comment: @Wimmel That would work but Is there a way to achieve the same result without creating another function? I want to keep everything inside the check function.

Comment: @sparta93 if you don't want to create another function, you need another parameter. The function needs to know if it called recursively (so it must not write any output), or if it is called from another function, so it must write the result to the screen. If you create two functions, the code is less complicated. You can also call the functions for example `check` and `check_and_write` to make clear what the function does.

Comment: @Wimmel I'm very new to c++, so I'm not sure how I would use an extra parameter to do the job.

Comment: @sparta93 for example, add `bool showresult`. Only if `showresult==true`, write output to the screen. If you make a recursive call, set `showresult` to `false`.

Comment: @Wimmel not sure if I'm going in the right direction, please look at my edit.

Comment: I think you're confused about the difference between returning a value and printing that value out.  Your original code snippet (now) correctly returns `true` or `false`; the problem is solved.  Simply get rid of all `cout` calls in the entire snippet: whoever calls your `check()` function can either (1) print the result out to `cout` if they want to do that, or (2) not do that if they don't (i.e. if just want to use the boolean value for something else).